# How to combine each element within a JSON list to each other

Tags: list, ansible, jinja2

I have a JSON object like this:

```
{ school: [
  {
   "teacher": [
                "Ms. Brown",
                "Mr. Schmidt"
            ],
   "student": [
                "H. Cosby",
                "L. Watson"
            ]
  },
  {
   "teacher": [
                "Mr. Port",
            ],
   "student": [
                "M. John",
                "A. Reilly"
            ]
  }
 ]
}
```

And I want to combine each element within an element with each other so like this:

`[Ms. Brown, H. Cosby], [Ms. Brown, L. Watson], [Mr. Schmidt, H. Cosby], [Mr, Schmidt, L.Watson], [Mr. Port, M. John], [Mr. Port, A. Reilly]`

I'm using Jinja2 and I can't separate the object into two. I managed with a for-loop, but that only outputs it like this:

`teacher:"Ms. Brown", "Mr. Schmidt" student:"H. Cosby", "L. Watson"`

which isn't what I'm looking for

[Edit:] Anyways found a solution. I just used

`{{ item.teacher | product(item.student) | map('join', ', ') | join(', ') }}`

within a for-loop. The solution seems easier than I thought lol.

Answer (score 0):

For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ school|json_query('[].*')|flatten(levels=1) }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ school|json_query('[].*')|flatten(levels=2) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - - Ms. Brown
    - Mr. Schmidt
  - - H. Cosby
    - L. Watson
  - - Mr. Port
  - - M. John
    - A. Reilly

  msg:
  - Ms. Brown
  - Mr. Schmidt
  - H. Cosby
  - L. Watson
  - Mr. Port
  - M. John
  - A. Reilly
```